# How can I use regex pattern to replace this following string

Tags: c#, regex, string

How can I use regex pattern to replace this following string

```
The result is {A or D} or {Ef or G}.
```

to

`The result is {AD} or {EfG}.`

Just need to remove that `_or_` in brackets.

Comment: Could you please edit title of your post to match answer (or at least body of your post)? "this string" is very non-descriptive...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this pattern with an empty string:

```
(?<=\{[^}]*)\sor\s(?=[^{]*\})
```

This makes use of .NET's lookbehinds which can be of arbitrary length to make sure the "or" is surrounded in brackets.

Comment: Syntax for replace: `Regex.Replace(subjectString, THE_REGEX, "");`

Comment: Or better yet... `Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"THE_REGEX", String.Empty)`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks! The word after `_or_` might be multiple characters. So I add a `*`: `(?<=\{[^}]*)\sor\s(?=[^{]*\})`

Comment: @Sean Oops, that was a mistake